# How can I use VueJS to navigate to another page/URL?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, amazon-sns

I'm very new to JS, so pardon if my code doesn't look the greatest. Anyway, I have a form that uses AWS SNS to send an email to my company with the information provided in the form. However, I don't have any feedback to let the user know that the form has been submitted.

I have been trying to use VueJS to navigate to another page or URL that says something along the lines of "Thank you. Your form has been submitted," but I'm getting a message saying "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined."

Ideally, I would love to just use "this.router.push('abc123.com');" so that after the form submits, it just goes to abc123.com.

Thank you all for any help that you can provide!

```
const routes = [
    { path: 'abc123.com'}
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    data(){
        return{
            yourName: null,
            from: null,
            phone: null,
            company: null,
            msg: null,
            timeframe: '',
            picked: '',
            proType: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        checkForm: function (){
            console.log(this.fullName);
            let result = null;
            let that = this;
            if ( this.from === null || this.from === '' ){
                alert( "Please enter a valid email address." )
                return false;
            } 
            if ( this.yourName === null || this.yourName === '' ){
                alert( "Please enter your full name." )
                return false;
            } 
            if ( this.msg === null || this.msg === '' ){
                alert( "Please enter a message." )
                return false;
            } 
            if ( this.picked === null || this.picked === '' ){
                alert( "Please choose a contact option." )
                return false;
            }
            if ( this.timeframe === null || this.timeframe === '' ){
                alert( "Please choose a time frame for the project." )
                return false;
            }
            if ( this.proType === null || this.proType === '' ){
                alert( "Please choose whether this is a new project or if it will be a modified application." )
                return false;
            } 
            that.publishSNS();
            that.redirect();                
        },

        publishSNS: function(){
                    //Removed confidential information for post
                });

                var sns = new AWS.SNS();

                var d = new Date();

                var params = {
                    Message: "Name: " + this.yourName + "\n" + "Company: " + this.company + "\n" + "Email: " + this.from + "\n" + "Phone Number: " + this.phone + "\n" + "Project Type: " + this.proType + "\n" + "Contact by: " + this.picked + "\n" + "Time Frame: " + this.timeframe + "\n" + "Message: " + this.msg,/* required */
                    Subject: 'Proposal Request' + ' (sent ' + d + ')',
                };
                sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
                });
        },

        redirect: function(){
                this.router.push('https://360works.com/action/email');
        }

    }

}).$mount('#app')
```

I expect the browser to navigate to abc123.com after the user submits the form.

Comment: It would be `window.location = 'https://360works.com/action/email';` instead of `this.router.push();`

Comment: @Mjh Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `router.push('url')` (remove the `this.`). You haven't declared `router` in your `data()`, so it wouldn't be set on `this`. It's just a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

in your code:
 `this.router`
should be
 **`this.$router`**

You need to define your router with path => component

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]
```

If you would like to redirect user to another site, you may work with location object directly without router

```
// Sets the new location of the current window.
window.location = "https://www.example.com";
```